# How to assert against an object passed to a mock repository

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq, assert

I have a code construct as below in the SUT

```
public class SUT
{

    //...

    public void Process()
    {
            // Does some work and creates new myDto(), and assigns field values.
            Update(myDto);
    }

    private void Update(MyDto myDto)
    {
        _repository.Update(myDto);
    }
}
```

I am passing a mock for `_repository` in my unit tests. I would like to verify if the Fields are properly set before invoking the `Update(MyDto myDto)` method

Is there a way to get the reference of the argument object through mock?

I would like to assert against the fields of the passed object `myDto`.

Something like.

```
Assert.AreEqual(1, myDto.Field1);
```

If not what are my options.

I am using `MSTest` and `Moq`.

Comment: You can capture the passed model in a callback and assert the values. You could also verify the argument given to the repository

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Mock<T>` has the Callback method that you can use like this;

```
myMock
   .Setup(x => x.Update(It.IsAny<MyDtoType>()))
   .Callback<MyDtoType>(VerifyDto);
```

And the method for verifications;

```
public void VerifyDto(MyDtoType dto) 
{
   Assert.AreEqual(1, myDto.Field1);
}
```